# Definition of a question with a fixed answer

Tags: word-meaning

I often come across the situations where I need to answer questions that were asked by the superiors. There questions are somehow not the real questions as the answers are fixed by the persons who ask them. For example, in a meeting; my boss asks me that

> Do you like other people to criticize you?

If I answered that

> No, I don't.

Then I would get punished by the boss for not saying

> Yes, I do.

by saying negative things to me and trying to humiliate me to make sure that she is still in charge. People should answer what she expects them to answer. If not, punishments will be conducted. I was the example for scaring the others for keeping them in her control. It was like a witch hunt, burn who ever doesn't say or act what they are expected to say or act.

Is there an idiom for this act, the witch hunt? And do we have a name for this kind of question in English?

Comment: Your example is confusing me. And, so the question!

Comment: Sorry, i edited the example but I am not sure does that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to separate the two different intentions your boss may have when asking their question.

One part, is the question and how it's asked.
The second part is what they do with the answer.

Your boss seems to be asking a **close-ended loaded question** meaning however you answer the question you will be wrong (loaded) and the answer is expected to be either yes-or-no or very short where the person answering can not expand upon or give reasons for their answer (closed-ended).

The way your boss is dealing with the answer is as a **teacher-student** or **parent-child** relationship, which is enabled by the shortness of the answer.  Your boss may not be picking on you personally, if it was not you it might have been someone else.

The behaviour is considered a **game**, not to be confused with **Game Theory**.  Your boss may be playing a game called "Nowadays" where they appear to know the correct answer for everything.

The way out of this game is to either not answer the question in the first place, or to give an elaborate answer which would cause a **peer-to-peer** discussion and not just a short yes-or-no answer. However this may cause other frictions since you may have taken their "fun" away.

On the other hand, if you know what answer your boss is looking for and you decide to answer differently, knowing the consequences, then you may need to look at that also.

Comment: Being forced to lie to oneself in every meeting is not easy but I understand your advise. I have done that before but it didn't help as it made me feel like I am no one.

Comment: When it rains, you get wet, maybe go some place sunny.

Answer (score 2):

A question where the speaker knows or doesn't want an answer is called a **rhetorical question**. See [here](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/rhetorical-question-examples.html) for more information.

For example, if you think that somebody is trying to cheat or trick you, you can ask:

> Do you think I was born yesterday?

Obviously not: the real question is "do you think I'm like a baby, who can easily be fooled?"

There are many rhetorical questions that are used as a humourous way of answering "yes" to a question, by asking another question where the answer is definitely "yes", for example if somebody says "Are you coming with us for a beer?" You can reply

> Is the pope a catholic?
>
> Do bears shit in the woods?

Comment: Does a rhetorical question create bad consequences to the person who answers the question in the way that is not expected by the person who asks the rhetorical question?

Comment: The whole point of a rhetorical question is that only one answer is right:  for your question, the correct answer is "Of course not!". When used by a bullying boss, you have to give the answer **that everybody knows is wrong**. This is the boss's way of demonstrating to you, and to everybody else, that he or she controls you.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have a boss who is 'difficult, pushy or rude and maybe downright abusive'.

There are a couple of words we can use to describe these bosses who tries to control everything, a 'control-freak' or even an 'intimidator' can be used. I think you can say she's a 'bully', too. More specifically what she does is 'verbal bullying' that is any bullying that is done by speaking, e.g. calling names, spreading rumors, threatening somebody, and making fun of others.

There are some idioms that I can think of:

1. Crack the whip

If you crack the whip, you use your authority to make someone obey you or work more efficiently, usually by threatening them, e.g.

Every so often I'll crack the whip to make sure we meet the deadline.

2. Bulldoze into doing

A person who is bulldozed into doing something is forced to do it, especially by being bullied or intimidated.
The immigrants we bulldozed into accepting the work.

3. My way or the highway

If you say to someone 'it's my way or the highway', you are telling them that either they accept to do as you say or they leave the project.

You don't have much choice when someone says: 'it's my way or the highway.'!

4. Also "boss around", which is very common, works to describe the act of giving someone orders in a forceful and unpleasant way e.g.

My older brothers and sisters are always bossing me around.

What gives you the right to boss around everyone on the playground?

The question as Peter already said is called a close ended loaded question. I just described how she acts

Comment: Thank Azad. These are all new phrases to me and they are very useful to me.

Comment: No problem pal, happy you liked them 